# How does MVC decide which constructor to hit when there are multiple constructors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

How does MVC decide which constructor to hit when there are multiple constructors? I have injected dependency in one constructor but another is being hit.

Comment: Depends on the container being used but most select the constructor with the most parameters that it can find dependencies for to inject. It's in the source code on GitHub if you want to check.

Comment: What if constructors have same number of parameters?

Comment: How does MVC decide which constructor to hit? Basically the same way code decides what overloaded method to use. Your IOC container can be configured to pass in the parameters for your services etc into the constructor. If not configured properly you will see "no parameter less constructor" error or if you have an empty constructor that will be hit. Hope that helps

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Are you talking about ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core MVC? Are you talking about the creation of Controller types or other types? Are you using the out-of-the-box implementation or an external library?

Comment: @Steven It's not vague. I have tagged my question with ASP.NET MVC.  Now what is your answer?